# Regex for validating numbers and characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a string that contains a number (the number can't be 0 or have zeros at the begining) or a number followed by a single characters in the range a-z or A-Z.  So, these are all valid

```
2, 12, 1, 324534A, 2Y, 934d
```

but these are all invalid

```
000R, 0, 0D, D3, 23432dddd, 234Q343.
```

Can someone show me the correct regex expression for this?

Comment: thanks Oded for the format tidy up.

Comment: BTW - I suggest learning Regex - it is a useful tool. Mastering Regular Expressions is the best book on the subject.

Comment: As soon as I finish reading the book I have on EF I will look into Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should match.

```
^[1-9]\d*[a-zA-Z]?$
```

Breakdown:

```
^           - Match start of string
[1-9]       - Followed by one digit (1-9), no 0
\d*         - Followed by any number of digits (can contain digits from 
              other cultures). If you want to constain use [0-9] instead of \d
[a-zA-Z]?   - Followed by either one character or none
$           - Followed by end of string
```

Comment: @t3hn00b - Correct. Was updating as you were commenting. Wasn't clear if a `0` was allowed within the string, but looks like it is.

Answer (score 3):

`^[1-9]\d*[a-zA-Z]?$` should do it.

- `[1-9]` - one digit 1-9
- `\d*` - possibly several digits 0-9
- `[a-zA-Z]?` - optional lower/uppercase character (may not cover accents etc.)
- `^...$` - will only match entire string, not substring.

Comment: This will fail on `2`, which is valid.

Comment: I certainly do need it to match the entire string and I don't want accents so as long as this is correct this should do it.

Comment: @Oded Thanks, got my `*` and `+` mixed up. I think it's OK now.

Comment: see this is why I don't trust myself to do it :-)